# Adding Vaadin to already working SpringBoot web app (Gradle)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, vaadin

I am developing my first web app with Spring Boot, Gradle, Hybernate. My back end is working (checked by Postman requests). I now want to add client side to same Intellij project (is it a good practice?) to add frontend for client side. HOw do I add Vaadin correctly? I attach my attempt (Gradle and app configuration) , but i cannot see my vaadin views in browser

```html
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.vaadin' version '20.0.0'

}


version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = "https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.13'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30'
    implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin:24.1.9'
    implementation "com.vaadin:vaadin-core:20.+"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.210'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

[image]
enter image description here

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); "but i cannot see my
vaadin views in browser" - what does that mean? Has the application and
vaadin successfully started (you should see vaadin in the logs and the
front-end-compiler working)?  Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)